# How to logging with Log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

i try to use log4net for logging on my wep project. Using EntityFramework and LINQ for database. I added these into **web.config** file

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>

 <log4net>
    <logger name ="DBLogger">
      <level value="ALL"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="data source=localhost;initial catalog=CATALOG_NAME;persist security info=False;user id=DB_USER;password=DB_PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" />

      <commandText value="INSERT INTO RCN_OPERATION_LOGS ([DATE],[THREAD],[LEVEL],[LOGGER],[MESSAGE],[EXCEPTION]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread ip=%property{ip}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>



 <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
            name="textWriterTraceListener"  type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\log4net_debug.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config"/>
    <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
</appSettings>
```

Added this line into **AssemblyInfo.cs:**

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "web.config", Watch = true)]

And **Global.asax.cs:**

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

I created a Logger class like this;

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FITMutabakat.BLL.Base
{
    public class Logger : Manager
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("DBLogger");

        public void AddLog(string user, string loggertype, string logprocess, string mesaj, string data, Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerAdd(logger, loggertype, logprocess, user, data, mesaj, ex);
            this.Context.SaveChanges();
        }


        public static void LoggerAdd(log4net.ILog logger, string LoggerType, string LogProcess, string User, string Data, string LogMessage, System.Exception Ex)
        {
            try
            {
                if (LoggerType == "InfoFormat")
                {
                    object[] args = new object[4];
                    logger.Info("sdf");

                    if (Data != null)
                    {
                        args[0] = LogProcess;
                        args[1] = User;
                        args[2] = Data;
                        args[3] = LogMessage;
                        logger.InfoFormat("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}] [{3}]", args);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        args[0] = LogProcess;
                        args[1] = User;
                        args[2] = LogMessage;
                        logger.InfoFormat("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}] ", args);
                    }
                }
                else if (LoggerType == "Fatal")
                {
                    if (Data != null)
                    {
                        object[] args = new object[4];
                        args[0] = LogProcess;
                        args[1] = User;
                        args[2] = Data;
                        args[3] = LogMessage;
                        string ermes = string.Format("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}] [{3}]", args);
                        logger.Fatal(ermes, Ex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object[] args = new object[4];
                        args[0] = LogProcess;
                        args[1] = User;
                        args[2] = LogMessage;
                        string ermes = string.Format("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}] ", args);
                        logger.Fatal(ermes, Ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logger class is called when the user login:

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.AddLog(oUser.USERNAME, "InfoFormat", "KullanıcıIslem", "Kullanıcı sisteme giriş yaptı.", null, null);
```

But any log added to database. Where is problem, i couldn't find. 
When program is running log4net write these into debug file but getting any error.

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a]. Loaded from [C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\05d71218\bc109529\assembly\dl3\d1df1039\3eae6e67_6b57d101\log4net.dll]. (.NET Runtime [4.0.30319.34209] on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [FITMutabakat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [FITMutabakat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\05d71218\bc109529\assembly\dl3\a6a085ea\52e3a93b_3a6ed101\FITMutabakat.dll]
log4net: Assembly [FITMutabakat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [FITMutabakat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using file [C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\FITMutabakat\web.config] watching for file updates
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using file [C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\FITMutabakat\web.config]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using stream
log4net: loading XML configuration
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Retrieving an instance of log4net.Repository.Logger for logger [DBLogger].
log4net: Setting [DBLogger] additivity to [True].
log4net: Logger [DBLogger] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: Logger [DBLogger] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: Loading Appender [AdoNetAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Setting Property [BufferSize] to Int32 value [100]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionType] to String value [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionString] to String value [data source=localhost;initial catalog=MUTABAKAT_DEV;persist security info=False;user id=sa;password=369900;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework]
log4net: Setting Property [CommandText] to String value [INSERT INTO RCN_OPERATION_LOGS ([DATE],[THREAD],[LEVEL],[LOGGER],[MESSAGE],[EXCEPTION]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_date]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [DateTime]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@thread]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%thread ip=%property{ip}]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ip=] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [property] Option [ip] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_level]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [50]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%level]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@logger]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%logger]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@message]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [4000]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%message]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@exception]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [2000]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Created Appender [AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [AdoNetAppender] to logger [DBLogger].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
log4net: Loading and watching configuration for default repository from AppSettings specified Config path [C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\FITMutabakat\log4net.config]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using file [C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\FITMutabakat\log4net.config] watching for file updates
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using file [C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\FITMutabakat\log4net.config]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using stream
log4net: loading XML configuration
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: Loading Appender [AdoNetAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Setting Property [BufferSize] to Int32 value [100]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionType] to String value [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionString] to String value [data source=localhost;initial catalog=MUTABAKAT_DEV;persist security info=False;user id=sa;password=369900;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework]
log4net: Setting Property [CommandText] to String value [INSERT INTO RCN_OPERATION_LOGS ([DATE],[THREAD],[LEVEL],[LOGGER],[MESSAGE],[EXCEPTION]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_date]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [DateTime]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@thread]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%thread ip=%property{ip}]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ip=] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [property] Option [ip] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_level]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [50]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%level]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@logger]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%logger]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@message]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [4000]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%message]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@exception]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [2000]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Created Appender [AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [AdoNetAppender] to logger [root].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using .config file section
log4net: Application config file is [C:\HttpRoot\FITMutabakat\FITMutabakat\web.config]
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Retrieving an instance of log4net.Repository.Logger for logger [DBLogger].
log4net: Setting [DBLogger] additivity to [True].
log4net: Logger [DBLogger] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: Logger [DBLogger] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: Loading Appender [AdoNetAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Setting Property [BufferSize] to Int32 value [100]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionType] to String value [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionString] to String value [data source=localhost;initial catalog=MUTABAKAT_DEV;persist security info=False;user id=sa;password=369900;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework]
log4net: Setting Property [CommandText] to String value [INSERT INTO RCN_OPERATION_LOGS ([DATE],[THREAD],[LEVEL],[LOGGER],[MESSAGE],[EXCEPTION]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_date]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [DateTime]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@thread]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%thread ip=%property{ip}]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ip=] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [property] Option [ip] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_level]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [50]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%level]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@logger]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%logger]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@message]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [4000]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%message]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@exception]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [2000]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Created Appender [AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [AdoNetAppender] to logger [DBLogger].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [FITMutabakat.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [FITMutabakat.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\05d71218\bc109529\assembly\dl3\4f082a23\1998a73a_3a6ed101\FITMutabakat.BLL.dll]
log4net: Assembly [FITMutabakat.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [FITMutabakat.BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists, using repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

Comment: Your post is too short.

Comment: Watch this. Best log4net tuttorial I have found. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAdQ_QwNww

Comment: Your DB password is in the log4net output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things I can see which may be missing and may be the reason why your logger isn't working.

Firstly, in the Global.asax.cs file I would have:

```
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

    void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        log.Error("App_Error", ex);
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

Then in the web.config file I can't see you having a `<root>` tag within the log4net tags anywhere. It looks like you're trying to do that with `<logger>` which I'm not sure where that's from. Also I'd change the buffer size from 100 to 1 (so rather than waiting for 100 before it writes to the DB it writes each log). I'd change the whole section to:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=localhost;initial catalog=CATALOG_NAME;persist security info=False;user id=DB_USER;password=DB_PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" />

  <commandText value="INSERT INTO RCN_OPERATION_LOGS ([DATE],[THREAD],[LEVEL],[LOGGER],[MESSAGE],[EXCEPTION]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread ip=%property{ip}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
```